# I have white screen when app is launched (localizations features)

Tags: flutter

I have a white screen when i launch the app in the emulator since i have added localizations features, my code is :

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'login.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';
import 'home.dart';
import 'globals.dart' as globals;
import 'package:awesome_page_transitions/awesome_page_transitions.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:onesignal_flutter/onesignal_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'application_localizations.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyApp_State createState() {
    return MyApp_State();
  }
}

class MyApp_State extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  final appTitle = 'FORTUNE ISLAND';

  String mail='';
  String pass='';

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
  }

  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    if (!mounted) return;

    OneSignal.shared.setLogLevel(OSLogLevel.verbose, OSLogLevel.none);

    var settings = {
      OSiOSSettings.autoPrompt: false,
      OSiOSSettings.promptBeforeOpeningPushUrl: true
    };


    // NOTE: Replace with your own app ID from https://www.onesignal.com
    await OneSignal.shared.init("xxx", iOSSettings: settings);

    OneSignal.shared.setInFocusDisplayType(OSNotificationDisplayType.notification);
    OneSignal.shared.getPermissionSubscriptionState().then((response) {
      globals.OneSignal_ID = response.subscriptionStatus.userId.toString();
      print("ONESIGNAL USER_ID : "+globals.OneSignal_ID);
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'FORTUNE ISLAND',
        theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            inputDecorationTheme: const InputDecorationTheme(
              labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            fontFamily: 'PoetsenOne',
            scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xFFEFEFEF)
        ),
        // List all of the app's supported locales here
        supportedLocales: [
          Locale('en', 'US'),
          Locale('fr', 'FR'),
        ],
        // These delegates make sure that the localization data for the proper language is loaded
        localizationsDelegates: [
          // A class which loads the translations from JSON files
          AppLocalizations.delegate,
          // Built-in localization of basic text for Material widgets
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          // Built-in localization for text direction LTR/RTL
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
        // Returns a locale which will be used by the app
        localeResolutionCallback: (locale, supportedLocales) {
          // Check if the current device locale is supported
          for (var supportedLocale in supportedLocales) {
            if (supportedLocale.languageCode == locale.languageCode &&
                supportedLocale.countryCode == locale.countryCode) {
              return supportedLocale;
            }
          }
          // If the locale of the device is not supported, use the first one
          // from the list (English, in this case).
          return supportedLocales.first;
        },
        home: Builder(
            builder: (context) => Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                        end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                        colors: <Color>[
                          Colors.blue[300],Colors.blue[400]
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Scaffold(
                    appBar: new AppBar(
                      title: new Text("FORTUNE ISLAND",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Azonix')),
                      flexibleSpace: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                            colors: <Color>[
                              Colors.blue[400],Colors.blue[600],Colors.blue[800]
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    body:
                    Center(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            margin : const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:20),
                            child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.solidGem,color: Colors.amber[200],size:70),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:30),
                            child : Text("FORTUNE ISLAND",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 30,fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,fontFamily: 'Azonix')),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin : const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:30),
                            child: Text('JEU 100 % GRATUIT 100 % GAGNANT',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 15,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin : const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:30),
                            child: Text("GAGNEZ DES CADEAUX ET DU CASH !!!",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 15,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                          ),
                          RaisedButton(
                            textColor: Colors.white,
                            color: Colors.green,
                            child : Text("COMMENCER",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 15,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                            onPressed: () async {
                              bool islog = await isconnect();
                              if (islog==false) {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  AwesomePageRoute(
                                    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                                    exitPage: widget,
                                    enterPage: LoginPage(),
                                    transition: RotateUpTransition(),
                                  ),
                                );
                              }
                              else {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  AwesomePageRoute(
                                    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                                    exitPage: widget,
                                    enterPage: HomePage(),
                                    transition: RotateUpTransition(),
                                  ),
                                );
                              }
                            },
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ]
            )
        )
    );
  }

  Future <bool> isconnect() async {
    // Create storage

    final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

// Read value

    mail = await storage.read(key: "e");
    pass = await storage.read(key: "p");

    if (mail!=null && pass!=null) {

      var url = 'https://www.fortune-island.com/app/login.php';

      // Store all data with Param Name.
      var data = {'email': mail, 'password': pass};

      // Starting Web API Call.
      var response = await http.post(url, body: json.encode(data),headers: {'content-type': 'application/json','accept': 'application/json'});

      print(json.decode(response.body));
      // Getting Server response into variable.

      Map <String,dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);

      // If the Response Message is Matched.
      if (map["status"] == 1) {
        // l'email et le mot de passe sont correct
        final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

        await storage.write(key: "i", value: map["id_membre"]);
        await storage.write(key: "e", value: mail);
        await storage.write(key: "p", value: pass);
        await storage.write(key: "t", value: map["jwt"]);

        globals.id_membre=map["id_membre"];
        globals.token=map["jwt"];
        globals.credits=double.parse(map["credits"]);
        globals.gems=double.parse(map["gems"]);

        OneSignal.shared.setExternalUserId(map["id_membre"]);
        return true;
      }
      else {
        // l'email et mot de passe stocké ne permettent pas de se connecter
        // rediriger vers la fenêtre de login
        return false;
      }
    }
    else {
      // email et password n'existe pas
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

I think there is a problem perhaps with setstate(). Can you what is wrong in all this code ?
I use statefullwidget, it can be perhaps the problem no ? If i delete all the code who do the localizations it works but at the moment i receive white screen in emulator

Answer (score 0):

Your flutter localisation is loading the translation assets, any operation like this or any async operation can cause some delay in rendering. Any delay in rendering will result in white blank screen. Perhaps you could await the localisation loading, or load before you build your widget.

Try this, it may not work, also I refactored your code little bit. Salvage things if you can

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'login.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';
import 'home.dart';
import 'globals.dart' as globals;
import 'package:awesome_page_transitions/awesome_page_transitions.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:onesignal_flutter/onesignal_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'application_localizations.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyApp_State createState() {
    return MyApp_State();
  }
}

class MyApp_State extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  final appTitle = 'FORTUNE ISLAND';

  String mail='';
  String pass='';

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
    await AppLocalizations.ensureInitialized();
  }

  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    if (!mounted) return;

    OneSignal.shared.setLogLevel(OSLogLevel.verbose, OSLogLevel.none);

    var settings = {
      OSiOSSettings.autoPrompt: false,
      OSiOSSettings.promptBeforeOpeningPushUrl: true
    };


    // NOTE: Replace with your own app ID from https://www.onesignal.com
    await OneSignal.shared.init("xxx", iOSSettings: settings);

    OneSignal.shared.setInFocusDisplayType(OSNotificationDisplayType.notification);
    OneSignal.shared.getPermissionSubscriptionState().then((response) {
      globals.OneSignal_ID = response.subscriptionStatus.userId.toString();
      print("ONESIGNAL USER_ID : "+globals.OneSignal_ID);
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'FORTUNE ISLAND',
        theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            inputDecorationTheme: const InputDecorationTheme(
              labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            fontFamily: 'PoetsenOne',
            scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xFFEFEFEF)
        ),
        // List all of the app's supported locales here
        supportedLocales: [
          Locale('en', 'US'),
          Locale('fr', 'FR'),
        ],
        // These delegates make sure that the localization data for the proper language is loaded
        localizationsDelegates: [
          // A class which loads the translations from JSON files
          AppLocalizations.delegate,
          // Built-in localization of basic text for Material widgets
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          // Built-in localization for text direction LTR/RTL
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
        // Returns a locale which will be used by the app
        localeResolutionCallback: (locale, supportedLocales) {
          // Check if the current device locale is supported
          for (var supportedLocale in supportedLocales) {
            if (supportedLocale.languageCode == locale.languageCode &&
                supportedLocale.countryCode == locale.countryCode) {
              return supportedLocale;
            }
          }
          // If the locale of the device is not supported, use the first one
          // from the list (English, in this case).
          return supportedLocales.first;
        },
        home: Builder(
            builder: (context) => Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                        end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                        colors: <Color>[
                          Colors.blue[300],Colors.blue[400]
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Scaffold(
                    appBar: new AppBar(
                      title: new Text("FORTUNE ISLAND",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Azonix')),
                      flexibleSpace: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                            colors: <Color>[
                              Colors.blue[400],Colors.blue[600],Colors.blue[800]
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    body:
                    Center(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            margin : const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:20),
                            child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.solidGem,color: Colors.amber[200],size:70),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:30),
                            child : Text("FORTUNE ISLAND",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 30,fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,fontFamily: 'Azonix')),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin : const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:30),
                            child: Text('JEU 100 % GRATUIT 100 % GAGNANT',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 15,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin : const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:30),
                            child: Text("GAGNEZ DES CADEAUX ET DU CASH !!!",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 15,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                          ),
                          RaisedButton(
                            textColor: Colors.white,
                            color: Colors.green,
                            child : Text("COMMENCER",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 15,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                            onPressed: () async {
                              bool islog = await isconnect();
                              if (islog==false) {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  AwesomePageRoute(
                                    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                                    exitPage: widget,
                                    enterPage: LoginPage(),
                                    transition: RotateUpTransition(),
                                  ),
                                );
                              }
                              else {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  AwesomePageRoute(
                                    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                                    exitPage: widget,
                                    enterPage: HomePage(),
                                    transition: RotateUpTransition(),
                                  ),
                                );
                              }
                            },
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ]
            )
        )
    );
  }

  Future <bool> isconnect() async {
    
    // Create storage
    final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
    
    // Read value
    mail = await storage.read(key: "e");
    pass = await storage.read(key: "p");

    if (mail!=null && pass!=null) {

      var url = 'https://www.fortune-island.com/app/login.php';

      // Store all data with Param Name.
      var data = {'email': mail, 'password': pass};

      // Starting Web API Call.
      var response = await http.post(url, body: json.encode(data),headers: {'content-type': 'application/json','accept': 'application/json'});

      print(json.decode(response.body));
      // Getting Server response into variable.

      Map <String,dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);

      // If the Response Message is Matched.
      if (map["status"] == 1) {
        // l'email et le mot de passe sont correct
        final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

        await storage.write(key: "i", value: map["id_membre"]);
        await storage.write(key: "e", value: mail);
        await storage.write(key: "p", value: pass);
        await storage.write(key: "t", value: map["jwt"]);

        globals.id_membre=map["id_membre"];
        globals.token=map["jwt"];
        globals.credits=double.parse(map["credits"]);
        globals.gems=double.parse(map["gems"]);

        OneSignal.shared.setExternalUserId(map["id_membre"]);
        return true;
      }
        // l'email et mot de passe stocké ne permettent pas de se connecter
        // rediriger vers la fenêtre de login
        return false;
    }
      // email et password n'existe pas
      return false;
  }
}
```